# XNA EffectMaterial Parameter missing

Tags: c#, parameters, xna, effects, skinning

I'm trying to create lights with shadows on skinned models in my XNA project.

I have found great sample for this by J.Coluna 
https://jcoluna.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/xna-light-pre-pass-skinned-meshes/

However I have a big problem: in this sample in SkinnedMesh.cs in OnDraw method he sets value of "Bones" parameter, but when I'm trying to do this I have exception which claims that "Bones" parameter does not exist. After debugging I've found out that I have 13 parameters in EffectMaterial, but in sample there are 14 parameters, missing one is "Bones" and because of this I cannot draw my skinned models with lighting and shadow effects :(

Is there any option to add missing parameter? EffectMaterial is part of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics so I have no idea why I don't have this parameter...

EDIT:

I have exception in method

```
protected override void OnDraw(ModelMeshPart subMesh, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Effect effect)
{
    effect.Parameters["Bones"].SetValue(boneMatrixes);
}
```

Exception message: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyRenderer.dll"

I'm sure that parameter "Bones" is the problem, because it doesn't even exist.

Comment: Please show some code and the error message.

Comment: Is your model file using `SkinnedModelProcessor` as content processor?

Comment: Yes it is. I think I've compared every settings, properties etc. for everything ith sample, but couldn't find any solution :/